# C++ Access private member from a derived class to another derived class (both have the same base class)

Tags: c++, inheritance, private-members

So I have a base class with two derived classes (deriv1 and deriv2).
On the deriv2 class I need to access a private member from deriv1...
How can I do this?

Sample code:

```
    class base
    {
    private:

    public:
        base() {};
        ~base() {};
    };

    class deriv1 : public base
    {
    private:
        int m_member1;
    public:
        deriv1() {};

        ~deriv1() {};
    };

    class deriv2 : public base
    {
    private:
        int m_member2;
    public:
        deriv2() {};

        ~deriv2() {};
    int sum_members_because_yes(void)
    {
        return (deriv1::m_member1 + m_member2); // <---- :((
    }
};
```

**How can I access a private member from another derived class?**
I was trying to avoid using friend functions, or changing the private member to public... **What do you advice?**

Thank you! :)

Comment: You can only access public or protected members in derived classes.

Comment: `deriv2` has no reason to contain fields from `deriv1`. What are you trying to model ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access `deriv1` private data members from `deriv2`.
You have two options to overcome that :

**Do a getter to access your `m_member1` in your `deriv1` class.**

```
class deriv1 : public base
{
private:
    int m_member1;
public:
    int get_member1() const { return m_member1; }
[...]
}
```

**Use `protected` on `m_member1` and make your `deriv2` also derived from `deriv1`.**

```
 class deriv1 : public base
 {
 protected:
   int m_member1;
   [...]
 }

class deriv2 : public base, public deriv1
{ 
  [...]
}
```

Use the option which seem to be coherent with your context.